# How do you write “conquer” in Korean?

Tags: grammar, translation, verb

I want to get a tattoo in Korean that means “conquer”. Conquer as in overcoming a weakness or conquering your fears. Please let me know. Thank you for your help!

Comment: have you checked a dictionary? try a google search for "how to say conquer in korean".

Comment: @user17915 With tattoos, using a dictionary is a bit risky - better to ask people who know the language.

Comment: @gaeguri you are right, but if the OP provides some words he looked up it will be easier for others to weigh in on which one is more appropriate

Answer (score 5):

I think 극복 will be the best word.

정복/정복하다 also means conquest/conquer, but is used more for conquests of war, conquering other countries, etc.  극복 is used for overcoming difficulties, fears, etc.

Actually, 극복하다 is the verb and 극복 is the noun, but standing alone I think that the simpler noun form 극복 is much more appropriate. (If you wanted to use a verb you'd want a different form like the imperative  극복하라).

Comment: Years ago I was searching on google translate but decided to ask someone that speaks the language and they told me it was 정복. Recently I checked again on google translate and it said that form meant “conquest” not “conquer” And I was worried it was the wrong “conquer” I was looking for. Thank you for responding and clarifying for me !